# What is this new[] a shorthand for?

Tags: c#, new-operator

I can't seem to find any documentation on what new[] is supposed to be. From the example below it seems to be an object array shorthand

```
var json = new[] {
            new object[] {"20-Jun-2008", 200 },
            new object[] {"20-Jun-2009", 250 }
        };
```

Comment: Can't you just check the type of ´json´ to see what that's returning?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

These are **implicitly typed arrays**.

See [C# 3.0 specifications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms364047%28VS.80%29.aspx#cs3spec_topic7).

> The syntax of array creation expressions (§7.5.10.2) is extended to
>   support implicitly typed array creation expressions:
>   array-creation-expression: ... `new   [   ]   array-initializer`
>
> In an implicitly typed array creation expression, the type of the
>   array instance is inferred from the elements specified in the array
>   initializer. Specifically, the set formed by the types of the
>   expressions in the array initializer must contain exactly one type to
>   which each type in the set is implicitly convertible, and if that type
>   is not the null type, an array of that type is created. If exactly one
>   type cannot be inferred, or if the inferred type is the null type, a
>   compile-time error occurs.
>
> The following are examples of implicitly typed array creation
>   expressions:
>
> ```
> var a = new[] { 1, 10, 100, 1000 };            // int[]
> var b = new[] { 1, 1.5, 2, 2.5 };            // double[]
> var c = new[] { "hello", null, "world" };      // string[]
> var d = new[] { 1, "one", 2, "two" };         // Error
> ```
>
> The last expression causes a compile-time error because neither int
>   nor string is implicitly convertible to the other. An explicitly typed
>   array creation expression must be used in this case, for example
>   specifying the type to be object[]. Alternatively, one of the elements
>   can be cast to a common base type, which would then become the
>   inferred element type.
>
> Implicitly typed array creation expressions can be combined with
>   anonymous object initializers to create anonymously typed data
>   structures. For example:
>
> ```
> var contacts = new[] {
>    new {
>       Name = "Chris Smith",
>       PhoneNumbers = new[] { "206-555-0101", "425-882-8080" }
>    },
>    new {
>       Name = "Bob Harris",
>       PhoneNumbers = new[] { "650-555-0199" }
>    }
> };
> ```

Answer (score 7):

The notation is an [implicitly typed array](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384090.aspx) declaration.

In your case, it is a array of object arrays.

Comment: How is it anonymous, isn't the variable `json` of type `object[][]`?

Answer (score 1):

It means that new[] is an implicitly typed array. Since it's implicitly typed, you have to assign something to it as in this example. Just as you have to with the `var` keyword.

Answer (score 1):

It's implicit typing.  Since all the elements in that collection are `object` arrays, the compiler can deduce that the array itself must be a collection of `object` arrays.