# Why can't I declare an implicitly typed array without an initializer?

Tags: c#, arrays

Why do I have to write `int` after `new` when I am declaring the array `num` without an initializer? E.g.

```
int[] num = new int[5];
```

For another array, `num1,` I just declared it first and then gave it values, and I didn't type `int` after `new` like I did for array `num`.

```
int[] num1 = new [] {1, 2, 3, 4};
```

Why does this shortcut not work for my first example?

Comment: If you don't like `new`, you can just do `int[] nums = { 1, 2, 3, 4 }` which is shorthand to do the same thing functionally.

Comment: Because C# supports inheritance.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem this is nothing to do with inheritance.

Comment: @Blorgbeard: well if you write `Foo name = new SubFoo(..)`...

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem And what does that have to do with the syntax for constructing an array?

Comment: In addition to answers, see also: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/arrays#array-initializers

Comment: for good or bad, C# is strict like that. In VB.Net it's just `Dim a = {1, 2, 3}`

Comment: @Slai The question specifically shows the C# code that has the array defined implicitly, when values are being provided.  Saying that you can do *the same thing* in VB isn't demonstrating a difference between the two, it's pointing out a *similarity*.

Comment: I want to note you can avoid the redundancy using `var num = new int[5];`.

Comment: I think https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9056311/what-is-this-new-a-shorthand-for?noredirect=1&lq=1 is related, and good reading for OP, but not an exact duplicate.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The type of the array can be inferred (under certain circumstances, which your example fullfills) if you provide the values for the array.  Since the values are all integers, the compiler is able to infer that you want an array of integers.  If you don't provide any values (or if the values aren't all implicitly convertible to the type of one of the values), it has no way of inferring what the type of the array should be, and so you need to specify it explicitly.

Answer (score 9):

The "full" syntax for declaring an array with values is `new int[] {1, 2, 3, 4};`.

Your `new [] {1, 2, 3, 4};` line is a shorthand syntax. It's an "implicitly typed" array. Because the values are all `int`, the array is automatically declared an `int[]`.

The reason you can't also write `int[] x = new [5];` is simply that this feature has not been implemented by the C# designers.

Answer (score 3):

Because you seem to expect that the way the compiler infers the type of the array is somehow based on the type to the left of the assignment operator:

```
int[] num = new[5];
```

Your thought process is:

1. `num` is an array of `int`s.
2. `new[5]` is an array of something.
3. something has to be `int` because that is `num`'s type.

That is not the way the compiler works. The compiler must figure out univocally the type to the right of the assignment expression and once it does, it will check if the assignment to whatever is on the left is valid.

In the syntaxes allowed in C#, the compiler always has enough information to figure out the type on the right side of the assignment (if it has any). Your proposed syntax wouldn't provide that information.

Comment: _That is not the way the compiler works. The compiler must figure out univocally the type to the right of the assignment expression and once it does, it will check if the assignment to whatever is on the left is valid_  -  is sweet and short answer :) is there any exception to this rule ?

Comment: also why `var array = new [] {1, "something"};` is not implicitly convertible to `object[]`

Answer (score 2):

In your first scenario, you're declaring an empty array, so you need to determine what type it is.

```
int[] num = new int[5]; // New empty array of integers with 5 slots.
```

However, in your second example, the type of the array is implied based on the values that you assign to the slots in the array.

```
int[] num1 = new [] {1, 2, 3, 4}; // New array of integers with 4 slots, already assigned.
```

The above works because every element in the array is of the same type.

If you were to do the following, a compilation error would occur because the type can't be inferred as the elements are different types.

```
var array = new [] {1, "something"}; // This won't compile.
```

But, if you declare one of the elements as a common base type, then it will store all of the elements as that base type.

```
var array = new [] {(object)1, "something", DateTime.Now}; // This is an array of objects.
```

Answer (score 0):

> why I have to write int after new when I am declaring array num with default values

You don't. There are a number of shorthands possible because often **the compiler can infer the type** of the array you are creating, like in your case.

So this is a perfectly fine declaration:

```
var num1 = new[] { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
```

See, there is no `int` here, but if you hover over `var` it will tell you the array is an `int[]`.

It is getting harder when you are mixing types:

```
var num1 = new [] { "1", 1 };
```

Then the compiler doesn't know and forces you to specify a type.

Comment: why `var num1 = new [] { "1", 1 };` is not implicitly convertible to `object[]` ?

Comment: Because `1` isn't an object. @rahul

Comment: thanks !! but `var num1 = new[] { new object(), 1 };` is implicitly convertible to `object[]` I mean there must be some rule governing this conversion.